# Swift - Remove intersecting lines

Tags: swift, uiview, draw

Help! How do I remove the intersecting lines so I will have only the outside shape?

[image]

What do I need to change in this to remove the intersecting lines?

```
let width = 300
func circle(withRadius radius: CGFloat) -> UIView {
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: width * (1/2), y: width * (1/3)), radius: 80, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
    path.append(UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: width * (1/3), y: width * (2/3)), radius: 80, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true))
    path.append(UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: width * (2/3), y: width * (2/3)), radius: 80, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    backView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    return backView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general case you need to solve a quadratic equation to calculate point where circles are intersected. The equation of circle is (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 = r^2, where (x0,y0) center of a circle. But I found some similar points for determine values of width and radius.

```
    let width: CGFloat = 300
    let radius: CGFloat = 80

    let point1 = CGPoint(x: width * (1/2), y: width * (1/3))
    let point2 = CGPoint(x: width * (1/3), y: width * (2/3))
    let point3 = CGPoint(x: width * (2/3), y: width * (2/3))

    circle(center: point1, withRadius: radius, startAngle: .pi - .pi/10, endAngle: .pi * 2 + .pi/10)
    circle(center: point2, withRadius: radius, startAngle: .pi / 3.5, endAngle: .pi / 3.5 + .pi * 1.11)
    circle(center: point3, withRadius: radius, startAngle: .pi * 1.6, endAngle: .pi * 1.72 + .pi)

    func circle(center: CGPoint, withRadius radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

        backView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

Comment: can you explain to me how did you calculate the startAngle and endAngle? I can'y figure how to use the equation you post it. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is by calculating the position of the 3 exterior point where the circles cut. (The point circled in red in the image).
[image]

Then you calculate the center of those points (we will call this point the center). After, you want to calculate the distance between one exterior point and the center (we will call this distance the radius).
You can then create an elipse at the center with the radius that we found before. This elipse has to be the same colour as the background and its zPosition greater than the other 3 circle. 
And done, the intersecting lines have now disapeared :)

(If you don't know how to create an elipse this is a script than can help you : )

```
let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
circle.position = center
circle.zPosition = 100 //Need to be greater than the others zPosition
self.addChild(circle)
```

Comment: So how does one do all the calculations you mention? Without that information this answer isn’t very helpful

Comment: I responded to the question but yeah i can add the code to calculate this.